# Rendering million elements on an html canvas effectively (and recreate render from server)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a html application which is based on a canvas. The canvas elements should have a huge grid, lets say the size of the grid is 1500 x 700. This results in 1,050,000 cells (that's slightly over a million).

So the first question is essentially how do we render this efficiently. We did ofcourse try a very naive implementation of generating rectangles in a loop.

But the page gets stuck when you try and loop over a million times.

The next question would be that I need to load data from a server to render this grid. I was thinking of having a character represent a color in every single cell of the 1500 x 700 grid. If we were to limit the colors to about 20 (using a letter from the alphabet), the file size seems to be limited to around 1 MB, which is not a problem.

But again after loading this file, the question is how do we write it onto the canvas without causing performance issues.

Also this is sort of a lite version of https://pixelcanvas.io/ that we are trying to accomplish. Which admittedly can seemingly handle a million pixels (or cells) on screen.

How would one go about implementing this efficiently.

Comment: Do you need to render the borders of each cells? So something like at least 3px x 3px per cells +1 (1px for borders + 1px for inner cell) and thus a canvas at least 4000px x 2000px wide? Are you sure your users will have a monitor big enough to show that? (Hint: you don't need to render what's not visible)

Comment: So there wont be any borders needed, it will be just colors, as to how big the pixels will be, let's assume 2px x 2px. On the pixelcanvas.io site, zoomed out it seems to be able to render 1500 x 800 pixels at a time (give or take) which is what I am sort of going for as well (but only with a limited canvas.

Answer (score 3):

Use an ImageData to act as your grid, then can *put* it to a non-visible canvas and draw that non-visible canvas on your visible one, scaled as you wish.

```js
// viewport size (canvas)
const vw = 500;
const vh = 500;
// image size (ImageData)
const iw = 2500;
const ih = 720;

// to handle the camera we use a DOMMatrix object
// which offers a few handful methods
const camera = new DOMMatrix();
const [ z_input, x_input, y_input ] = document.querySelectorAll( "[type='range']" );
[ z_input, x_input, y_input ].forEach( (elem) => {
  elem.oninput = updateCamera;
} );
function updateCamera() {
  const z = +z_input.value;
  const x = +x_input.value;
  const y = +y_input.value;
  camera.a = camera.d = z;
  camera.e = vw / 2 - (x * z);
  camera.f = vh / 2 - (y * z);
  draw();
}

const colorinput = document.querySelector( "input[type='color']" );
let color = colorinput.value = "#FF0000";
colorinput.oninput = (evt) => {
  color = colorinput.value;
  draw();
};

// the visible canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
canvas.width = vw;
canvas.height = vh;
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
// we hold our pixel's data directly in an ImageData
const img = new ImageData( iw, ih );
// use a 32 bit view to access each pixel directly as a single value
const pixels = new Uint32Array( img.data.buffer );
// an other canvas, kept off-screen
const scaler = document.createElement( "canvas" );
// the size of the ImageData
scaler.width = iw;
scaler.height = ih;
const scalerctx = scaler.getContext( "2d" );

// fill with white, for demo
for(let i=0; i<pixels.length; i++) {
  pixels[ i ] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, down: false };
canvas.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  const canvasBBox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  // relative to the canvas viewport
  const x = evt.clientX - canvasBBox.left;
  const y = evt.clientY - canvasBBox.top;
  // transform it by the current camera
  const point = camera.inverse().transformPoint( { x, y } );
  mouse.x = Math.round( point.x );
  mouse.y = Math.round( point.y );
  
  if( mouse.down ) {
    addPixel( mouse.x, mouse.y, color );
  }
  draw();
};
canvas.onmousedown = (evt) => { mouse.down = true; };
document.onmouseup = (evt) => { mouse.down = false; };

function draw() {
  // first draw the ImageData on the scaler canvas
  scalerctx.putImageData( img, 0, 0 );

  // reset the transform to default
  ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 );
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, vw, vh );
  // set the transform to the camera
  ctx.setTransform( camera );

  // pixel art so no antialising
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  // draw the image data, scaled on the visible canvas
  ctx.drawImage( scaler, 0, 0 );
  // draw the (temp) cursor
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1, 1 );
}
function addPixel( x, y, color ) {
  const index = y * img.width + x;
  if( index > 0 && index < pixels.length ) {
    pixels[ index ] = parseColor( color );
  }
}
function parseColor( str ) {
  return Number( "0xFF" + str.slice(1).match(/.{2}/g).reverse().join("") );
}

// initial call
updateCamera();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: ivory;
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
z:<input type=range min=0.1 max=20 step=0.1 id=z-range><br>
x:<input type=range min=0 max=2500 step=0.1 id=x-range><br>
y:<input type=range min=0 max=720 step=0.1 id=y-range><br>
<input type=color><br>
<canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

If you need bigger area, use multiple ImageData objects and the same "trick".